# Complicated Linq to SQL Query

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, left-join

I'm struggling to work out what the Linq-to-SQL syntax is for a particular query. I could do this easily in SQL, but I can't quite get the correct syntax in Linq.

I have parent and child records in two database tables, linked by a foreign key. I want my result to return rows based on these rules:

1. Return exactly **1 row** per parent regardless of how many children exist.
2. Return null/zero values if the child doesn't exist.
3. Return related data from a child with a null condition. If more than one exists with a null condition then return just the **first** one.
4. Return a count of the number of child records with a non-null condition.

I have been playing around with this in [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DyU2Dh) for a while and I can't get it right. This is what I have so far (ignore the random descriptions!):

```
    IEnumerable<Parent> parents = new Parent[] { 
        new Parent { ID = 1, Description = "Apple" },
        new Parent { ID = 2, Description = "Orange" },
        new Parent { ID = 3, Description = "Pear" },
        new Parent { ID = 4, Description = "Banana" } };

    IEnumerable<Child> children = new Child[] {
        new Child { ID = 1, ParentID = 2, Description = "Mercury", Condition = null },
        new Child { ID = 2, ParentID = 3, Description = "Venus", Condition = null },
        new Child { ID = 3, ParentID = 3, Description = "Earth", Condition = null },
        new Child { ID = 4, ParentID = 4, Description = "Mars", Condition = null },
        new Child { ID = 5, ParentID = 4, Description = "Saturn", Condition = "> 5" } };

    /// What goes here...?
    var query = from p in parents
                join c in children on p.ID equals c.ParentID into jc                    
                from subchildren in jc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new Item { 
                    ParentID = p.ID, 
                    Description = p.Description, 
                    PrimaryChildID = subchildren == null ? 0 : subchildren.ID, 
                    SubDescription = subchildren == null ? null : subchildren.Description,
                    ConditionalCount = 0};

    foreach (var item in query) 
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}",
            item.ParentID, 
            item.PrimaryChildID,                              
            item.Description,                
            item.SubDescription, 
            item.ConditionalCount);
```

The output I get from this is:

```
1 0 Apple  0
2 1 Orange Mercury 0
3 2 Pear Venus 0
3 3 Pear Earth 0
4 4 Banana Mars 0
4 5 Banana Saturn 0
```

but I want this:

```
1 0 Apple  0
2 1 Orange Mercury 0
3 2 Pear Venus 0
4 4 Banana Mars 1
```

Can anyone help me with the correct syntax for this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `left join` in your case, you need a `group join` instead.

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx):-

```
The group join is useful for producing hierarchical data structures. 
It pairs each element from the first collection with a set of correlated elements
from the second collection.
```

Do it like this:-

```
var query = from p in parents
       join c in children
       on p.ID equals c.ParentID into g
       let firstNullElement = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Condition == null)
       select new
      {
         ParentID = p.ID,
         PrimaryChildID = firstNullElement != null ? firstNullElement.ID : 0,
         Description = p.Description,
         SubDescription = firstNullElement!= null ? firstNullElement.Description
                                                  : String.Empty,
         ConditionalCount = g.Count(x => x.Condition != null)
      };
```

Just to explain it properly, here is what will be generated before we project our actual required data using `select new { }`, (justifies the definition of `Group Join`):-

```
ParentId                    g
----------------------------------------------
1                          null

2          ID = 1, ParentID = 2, Description = "Mercury", Condition = null

3          ID = 2, ParentID = 3, Description = "Venus", Condition = null
           ID = 3, ParentID = 3, Description = "Earth", Condition = null

4          ID = 4, ParentID = 4, Description = "Mars", Condition = null
           ID = 5, ParentID = 4, Description = "Saturn", Condition = "> 5"
```

Now, since `g` is holding an `IEnumerable` of Child elements we can apply filter, project data, count or do whatever we want, as we did in our final statement using `select`. And also, as we can see there is no point of data coming from different child element.

Here is the complete [Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/38mZPW).

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer. Can I just check, is there a danger that the PrimaryChildID and SubDescription might come from different children records?

Comment: @BG100 - Didn't get you, might come from different children records as in?

Comment: @BG100 - Please check my edit, hope it makes sense :)

Comment: Different child records... meaning you are doing to independant calls to FirstOrDefault(), so I just wanted to check that both calls to FirstOrDefault would return info from the same child.

Comment: @BG100 - Okay had not considered your 3rd point, `to retrieve the first element`, please check my edit. So, not its clear? I am selecting the first element with `Condition = null`, and based on that selecting items like `SubDescription` & `PrimaryChildID `.

Comment: Ah perfect... exactly what I was after. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the thing

```
    var query = (from p in parents
                     select new
                     {
                         ParentID = p.ID,
                         Description = p.Description,

                         PrimaryChildID = children.Where(c => c.ParentID == p.ID && c.Condition == null).Count() == 0 ? 0 : children.OrderBy(c=>c.ID).FirstOrDefault(c => c.ParentID == p.ID && c.Condition == null).ID,
                         SubDescription = children.Where(c => c.ParentID == p.ID && c.Condition == null).Count() == 0 ? null : children.OrderBy(c => c.ID).FirstOrDefault(c => c.ParentID == p.ID && c.Condition == null).Description,
                         ConditionalCount = children.Where(c => c.ParentID == p.ID && c.Condition != null).Count()
                     }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my variant of query:

```
        var query = from p in parents
                    join c in children on p.ID equals c.ParentID into jc
                    from subchildren in jc.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        Parent = p,
                        Subchildren = subchildren
                    } into itemData
                    group itemData by itemData.Parent into g
                    select new Item
                    {
                        ParentID = g.Key.ID,
                        Description = g.Key.Description,
                        PrimaryChildID = g.Select(_ => _.Subchildren == null ? 0 : _.Subchildren.ID).FirstOrDefault(),
                        SubDescription = g.Select(_ => _.Subchildren == null ? null : _.Subchildren.Description).FirstOrDefault(),
                        ConditionalCount = 0
                    };
```